# ios double click home button event

Tags: ios

Is there anyway to capture double click home button event.

I know it will run into applicationWillResignActive, but there are many situations that application will run into applicationWillResignActive so I can NOT distinguish the double click home button event with other events.

Can anybody give me some hints?

My app is meeting a bug:
- On iOS 7, when double click home button, you can see running app with their current images. Because my app have some protection (I built a passcode view), so when user home button or double click home button, I will capture event to show my passcode view first. To do this, I place my code to show passcode on applicationWillResignActive.

- It works well, but another problem occurs, when user pull down notification or other action make app resign active, it will show my passcode view, this lead user feel very annoy. So I just want to show passcode view whenever user home button or doubleclick home button. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is the `applicationDidEnterBackground` event not useful for your case?

Comment: @Zen, yes, but it's useful for case press home button, when double click on home button, it seems not because in this case applicationDidEnterBackground not be called, just applicationWIllResginActive is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not.

Apple just don't allow you to access their hardware. The only thing you can do is to use frameworks to accsess those hardware. If there isn't any framework for that, there is just no way to do this without coding for jailbreak or something.

You can think about layers of the software.

1. Hardware independent = Like apps
2. Hardware using = For Example Camera Apps (Using some type of core Frameworks)
3. Hardware itself = NO permission to use that layer

The core frameworks give you the closes freature to code for the hardware.

[IOS Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html)

Comment: thank @MasterRazer, I'm quite sure that no solution, but I have to ask to find out any luck. My app have some problem related to this.

Comment: I've just add edit demonstrate my app problem, may you give me any idea

Comment: I know that kind of app and I don't think that that is very annoying. If a user downloads a app for secure passcodes or something else, they expect that. I own a app like this and I am really happy about this, cause sometimes I forgot to lock my phone and they were visible. So just leave it as it is. I don't think that there is another method for this, that apple provides you.

Comment: @pf2707 sorry for that, but I don't see a solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access any button clicks on the home button.

When it goes into `applicationWillResignActive` that's as a secondary result of the button click. Not a direct result.

i.e. the button is clicked, the OS interprets the click, then tells your app to go into background, then you get `applicationWillResignActive`.

Same when you receive a phone call etc...

Comment: Thank @Fogmeister, your answer is helpful for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of specifically detecting a double tap on the home button.

As you note, you should respond to `applicationWillResignActive`.

What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank @Ashley Mills, because my app need it to prevent bug, if there's no way to distinguish double click home event with others, maybe I need to accept the bug, as the bug is not quite critical.

Comment: You should ask a question giving specific details of your bug, and maybe we can help you with that!